# Finding strings within a list while using another list as reference python

Tags: python, string, substring

Let's say I have:

```
name_list = ["gxrgirl", "Octagon", "Nimble Momonga"]
feminine_words = ["girl", "princess", "wifey", "woman", "queen"]
```

I want to be able to detect feminine words within the `name_list` by using the `feminine_words` list.

So for example:

I would be able to detect the "girl" string within `gxrgirl` and have some output saying: `female`

I read somewhere that I can use `from builtins import any` , but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Anything in `builtins` doesn't require an import. You can just use `any` with no imports at all. `from builtins import any` is pointless.

Comment: `any(f in w for f in feminine_words for w in name_list)` ? probably a duplicate

Comment: Show what you've tried with more familiar tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `any()` without any `import` statement.

It can be solved by one line:

```
['female' if any(word in name for word in feminine_words) else '' for name in name_list]
# It gives the following result: ['female', '', '']
```